# What's the difference btw a pilot light & thermocouple in gas fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

A follow up to an earlier question. I have a new Heat & Glo Slimline fireplace, **MODEL SL-5X-IFT-G** hooked up to a propane tank. After many adjustments by technicians, there seems to be a reasonable set of flame heights (usually from 1 to 5, on a remote control). On the other hand, when the unit if clicked 'off', the flames die... but a residual source of heat persists. After several inspections, I discovered that there are 2 spots down in the burner where what looks like pilot lights are burning... 24 hrs a day. On a couple of occasions they've risen to low flames. (tried to attach a low quality photo but it doesn't work). I had understood that there's no 'pilot light' in a thermocouple arrangement. I'm having trouble getting straight answers from the dealer. Can anyone enlighten me -- no pun intended.

Comment: A thermocouple is used with pilot lights to shut off the gas if the pilot light goes out. Even on electronic start systems there is typically a thermocouple to serve the same purpose - if the spark doesn't light a flame you want to stop flowing gas. For, say, a gas cooktop it is assumed that you are standing there and would notice if the flame doesn't light, so no thermocouple is common there.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the model number of the fireplace.

Comment: Edit done - MODEL SL-5X-IFT-G

Answer (score 1):

If your unit does not use a pilot for ignition, and you have flame present when the gas control valve is supposed to be closed, this would indicate that the control valve is not closing all the way (it is leaking-by). This could be due to the control valve being defective or debris in the control valve.

A less likely (but possible) cause is that you have some other gas leak upstream of the control valve that is being ignited by the unit...

I don't see that your scenario would be related to a thermocouple/thermopile, as these units are designed to fail *safe*, i.e. lack of current from thermocouple causes valve to close.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. This is scary, because the dealer denies everything.  A technician will be here in 5 days. Is it safe to keep this 'burning on its own' for the 5 days? After that, I'm just going to shut the electrical feed.

Comment: There should be a manual gas shutoff valve. If there isn't supposed to be a pilot, **Use it.**

Comment: You mean the gas valve on the tank? Can that be shut off at any time?

Comment: There should be a shut-off valve just upstream of the appliance... somewhere near. If there isn't, then it would be prudent to shut off the main at the tank, because you basically have a gas leak right now. The fact that the leak is lit makes it fairly safe, but if it goes out... you have uncontrolled release just looking for a spark.

Comment: found it, gas is shut off. There did not seem to be any gas vapor in the house -- that was checked. Thanks for your advice. I'm off to buy to a propane gas detector.

Comment: I don't think you need a detection device. Propane for household use is odorized with mercaptans; you will smell any significant leak before it gets to an ignitable concentration (assuming you are home to smell it; if you aren't home then the detection device becomes useless anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

A "pilot light" is a small gas lamp.  It is on at all times.  It is there to provide the "source of fire" when the burner kicks on.  Water heaters and gas ranges also use pilot lights. Those, and Empire style wall and floor furnaces, can do just fine without electricity, *a huge advantage in some places*.

Because of the gas waste, some machines go to electronic controls where they eliminate the pilot light altogether and use an electronic spark ignition.  The problem with this system is it requires utility grid electricity to be up at all times. If the grid is down, your entirely gas appliance that doesn't need electricity, cannot run, which is stupid.

However for furnaces, people want wall-mounted thermostats. Not least, moving the thermostat away from the furnace makes it more accurate.  To do this, they use a **thermocouple**, which is a gadget that makes electricity when one side of it is hot and the other is cold. This makes very low voltage (millivolts) but high current. This current operates a gas valve, which opens the gas flow to the main burner.  So now you simply add an electrical switch to this circuit, so current flows in a triangle.  And the electrical switch is temperature activated, i.e. a thermostat.

```
 Thermocouple -> thermostat -> gas flow valve -> back to thermocouple.
```

Now we have proper thermostat control of the thing.  Note due to the high current, it needs a special "millivolt thermostat", not a common 24 volt thermostat. Just today I saw one of those misused for a millivolt furnace, I told them not to expect long life out of it.

However if your heart is absolutely set to use a 24 volt thermostat like the Nest to control a millivolt furnace, that can actually be done.  It will fail when AC power is lost, but a real millivolt thermostat can be wired in parallel with it so it will "fall back" onto the millivolt 'stat.

Answer (score 0):

A thermocouple indicates that a pilot light is lit (and may also power a "millivolt" thermostat) If the pilot light goes out the main gas won't turn on (due to lack of signal or power from the cold thermocouple) so you don't have a large gas leak - modern setups also cut off the pilot gas if the thermocouple isn't hot. Thus, you normally have to hold in a manual override while the thermocouple heats up when lighting the pilot flame.

You appear to be confusing this with "no standing pilot" operation, where a spark or hot surface igniter is used to light the flame (that would probably **also** use a thermocouple to ensure the flame is present and avoid large gas leaks if calling for flame with the flame out. Though one HSI I dealt with monitored the current in the HSI, not a TC)

Answer (score 0):

A thermocouple is an electrical device that sits in a flame and sends electrical signals generated by the flame. When the flame goes out, the electricity stops, and a valve device can use the presence or absence of electricity to decide if the gas should be on or not.

You will find thermocouples in both pilot light and spark start / hot glow gas controls.

To avoid the constant pilot light draw on your propane tank, you should get a spark start or hot glow fireplace (or at least a spark start / hot glow gas valve) instead. Then there is no pilot light. The gas will be lit by sparks, like a non-pilot-light gas stove, or by a hot-glowing device (can't think of the name) like a non-pilot-light gas oven.

Comment: Thanks to all, for the advice. Obviously, I'm not in a position to abandon the fireplace -- it's brand new. I need to know what's causing the glow and occasional small flare of flame when the unit is not in heating mode. I was assured by the dealership that there was no 'pilot light' -- that's where my confusion is, and I need outside advice, if I can get it. BTW, is there any danger in throwing the circuit-breaker open for a few minutes to see what happens? I'm afraid of gas leaks...